# Dynamic TOP query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm have two tables: sites and pages. Each site connected to zero or more pages. Each site contain a [credits] value (number).

I'm want to make a query that: return N (equal to [credits]) pages, of website which have one or more [credits].

Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (sites.Credits) pages.Id, sites.Id FROM sites, pages 
    WHERE sites.Credits > 0 AND sites.Id = pages.WebSites_Id
```

**Note** that each site can have a different value of [credits]. So, this TOP cannot be working globally.

Any solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause.  You are using `TOP` inappropriately, because it only applies to the entire result set.  Instead, think `row_number()`.

Here is one method using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT TOP (sites.Credits) pages.Id, sites.Id
FROM sites s CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT p.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      FROM pages p
      WHERE p.Id = p.WebSites_Id
     ) p
where seqnum <= s.credits;
```